# jQuery .show() - Chrome vs. IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm using this code within a `jQuery`AJAX` request:

```
beforeSend: function() {
    loading.show();
},
complete: function(){
    loading.hide();
}
```

`loading` looks this way: `var loading = form.siblings("img")`.

And the `css` for `loading` is:

```
display: none;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 30px;
height: auto;
```

The code works just fine with a minor inconsistency between Chrome and IE 11:

- in Chrome the `.show()` adds `display: block` to the `loading` element allowing the `.gif` to be centered:
  [image]
- in IE 11 the same method adds `display: inline`: [image]

Is there any way to alter this behavior directly within `jQuery` without having to force `.css("display", "block")` after the `.show()` method? And what would be the pitfalls of doing so?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting [`.css(propertyName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) for `.show()` , `.hide()`

```
var toggle = function toggle() {
  loading.css("display", function(index, display) {
    return display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
  })
};
```

---

```
beforeSend: function() {
  toggle()
},
complete: function(){
  toggle()
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var loading = $("img");
  var toggle = function toggle() {
    loading.css("display", function(index, display) {
        return display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
    })
  }
  $("button").click(function() {
    toggle()
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>click</button>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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">
```

Comment: Really nice approach! Thanks for suggesting it! Cheers!